# Unit Testing batman.js Apps

Tags: batman.js

Do you have any tips on how to unit test batman.js applications? I could not find any hints in the documentation. Which testing tools do you use? Any sample would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Capybara is great for functional testing, but that's not what you asked.  Granted it's kinda slow...

Answer (score 0):

Batman's new website has [a page for Batman.TestCase](http://batmanjs.org/docs/testing.html), which is a Ruby `Test::Unit`-like wrapper for QUnit and Sinon.js.

However, for my own use, I use Jasmine & Karma, set up after [this blog post](http://danott.co/posts/rails-javascript-testing-using-karma.html)